# Marshal safearray of struct inside struct

Tags: c++, c

I have the following code in C++ which I need to be able to call from C#:

```
struct Inner
{
 double data1;
 double data2;
};

struct Outer
{
 double data3;
 SAFEARRAY innerData;
};

int WINAPI ProcessData (Outer& outer )
{
  ...
}
```

I tried the following but it did not work What am I doing wrong?

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Inner 
{
 public double data1;
 public double data2;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Outer 
{
 public double data3;
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Safearray,ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct)]
 public Inner[] innerData;
}
```

Comment: There's no way to guess the element type from the declaration.  Use object[] if the array actually stores variants.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
  [StructLayoutAttribute (LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct Outer
  {
     public double data3;
     [MarshalAsAttribute (UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArrayUserDefinedSubType=typeof(Inner))]
     public Inner [] innerData;
  }
```

Comment: [MarshalAsAttribute (UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArrayUserDefinedSubType=typeof(Inner))] works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the attribute declaration is not correct as its refusing to compile...

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Outer
        {
            public double data3;
            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_SAFEARRAY)]
            public Inner[] innerData;
        }
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.