# Can safearrays take, and marshall, user defined types?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-c++, pinvoke, interop

I would like to move fairly complex types from the managed to native world and visa versa.

Currently this is being done by creating multidimensional safearrays, which has the advantage that marshalling is done for you, but means we end up with rather complex jagged arrays to get our heads around.

I have tried to put some structs into SAFEARRAYs but came across issues very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233766/marshal-safearray-of-struct-inside-struct) unanswered question. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221145.aspx) seems to imply that it is possible, but I am having little success. If this is possible, what are valid VT_ types in the following situation?

edit: Thanks! So this has to be a VT_RECORD.

```
struct Change
{
    PSTR key;
    PSTR val;
};

struct NodeChages
{
    int nodeId;
    SAFEARRY* changes; //CComSafeArray<Change>
};


STDAPI func(/*CComSafeArray<NodeChanges>*/ SAFEARRAY * f);
```

On the managed side I have.

```
public struct Change
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string key;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string value;
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NodeChanges
{
    public int nodeId;
     [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArrayUserDefinedSubType = typeof(CurveChange))]
    public Change[] changes;
}

[DllImportAttribute("My.dll", EntryPoint = "Func", PreserveSig = true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void Func(
   [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArrayUserDefinedSubType = typeof(NodeChange))]
   NodeChange[] changes
   );
```

But this (as in [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233766/marshal-safearray-of-struct-inside-struct)) gives me:

```
System.ArgumentException : The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

Comment: you use `VT_RECORD` for user defined types. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221198.aspx